# Struts actions class not able to get the value of textarea

Tags: java, html, struts2

I have written the below code to pass the value of the comments textarea to the action class of the struts once I submit the form. But, when I ran the code the Actions class is not able to get the value of the textarea. Can you please let me know what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<s:form method="post" id="formregister" action="survey" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="surveyComments" id="surveyComments" rows=4 cols=80 wrap=virtual 
        onkeydown="textCounter( this, f.Surv_Q99Count, 255 );" 
        onkeyup="textCounter( this, f.Surv_Q99Count, 255 );">
    </textarea>
</s:form>
```

Below is my `struts.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="5242880" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="rest"/>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="survey" class="eidms.survey.Survey">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">   

            </interceptor-ref>

            <result name="success">Confirmation.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
         </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Below is the action class

```
package eidms.survey;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.CreateSurvey;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.CreateSurvey_Input;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.CreateSurvey_Output;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.QuerySurvey_Output;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.Survey_spcWebservice;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.Survey_spcWebserviceStub;
import com.siebel.SurveyWebService.UNINCustomerSurveyWSLocator;

public class Survey extends ActionSupport {
    private String surveyComments;
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Survey.class);

    public String execute() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext()
                .get(org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
        Boolean isResponseCorrect = Boolean.FALSE;

        System.out.println("Comments are"+getComments());
        return "success";
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return surveyComments;
    }

    public void setComments(String surveyComments) {
        this.surveyComments = surveyComments;
    }
}
```

I got the following output

```
 Comments are null
```

Comment: You have `surveyComments` in JSP but `setComments` in action.

Comment: @Aleksandr M  What should I specify in the action?

Comment: Use the same name in JSP and in action.

Comment: Thanks a lot , It worked :)